# Why does performing multiple queries at once result in an error in Wordpress but not in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: wordpress

This is my query and how I do it:

```
$query_string = "DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN(SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product'); \n";
$query_string .= "DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product'"
$wpdb->query($query_string);
```

This will run and do exactly what it is supposed to do in phpMyAdmin. But in Wordpress it results in an error:

```
[WordPress-database error] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product'' at line 2 [for query] DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN(SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product'); 
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' Kirjoittaja: require_once('wp-admin/admin.php'), do_action('product_page_opencart-import'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, theme_slug_opencart_import
```

Notice that the error is in line 2. I have no logical explanation as to why the same query will not execute through Wordpress but will execute through phpMyAdmin.

The obvious easy solution is of course to run both queries separately, **but I will not accept that as an answer**, because later I will perform a database operation of several thousand queries. That is significantly faster to do by building everything into a single query string and running that instead of every one of them separately. This is also about principles: the syntax, at face value, is correct. It should therefore be possible.

Comment: Normal `mysqli_query` will only execute one query, and that function is what WP uses by default, AFAIK. It would need to use `mysqli_multi_query`, to perform multiple queries in one go. phpMyAdmin either uses the latter (or a PDO equivalent), or splits your input into individual queries by itself, and executes them one by one.

Comment: For muliiple queries in one query string pls refer to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Most applications realize that allowing multiple queries is an invitation to hackers to do naughty things.  Such hacking can happen in WP, but not in phpMyAdmin.

Simply put, get out of the habit of ever using multiple queries at once.

In some situations, it is convenient to put multiple queries in a Stored Procedure so the user can do a single `CALL` to perform it.